# Javascript Redirect Without Originating Referrer

Tags: javascript, redirect, referrer

I have a site that sells services/products. Let's call that Website-A. I also have another site (Website-B) that gets traffic from Website-A, for finalizing the orders and checking out, eventually to Website-C (payment processor). 
As of last week, I have revamped my check out process. Basically, my goal is to do a javascript redirect from Website-B to Website-C (payment processor). However, I do not want the payment processor (Website-C) to see the traffic/referral coming from Website-A.

So my question very simply put is: If Website-A sends traffic to Website-B, and then Website-B automatically redirects the user to Website-C, will Website-C be able to somehow tell what the originating referrer is? Or will they only see the traffic coming from Website-B? (Which is what I want).

Is there anything I can do to ensure that referrer info is not carrier from Website-A to Website-C, once redirected? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `will Website-C be able to somehow tell what the originating referrer is?` - have you checked?

Comment: That's what I'm asking. I have no control over Website-C. It's the payment processor site. I prefer to not have them see Website-A as a referrer. I'm looking to see if anyone knows before I implement.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I must've misread the question, I thought you owned all 3 :p

Comment: Nope, just Website-A and Website-B.